# Bluemix Kafka streams

Tags: d3.js, stream, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, apache-kafka-streams

Does the latest version of IBM Message Bus support Kafka Streams 
(described here: http://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/). Any examples / samples on how to do this? If yes, can this be done with node.js?

What I am trying to do is

1. stream data from source database (Cloudant) to a Kafka stream (a connector service exists in Bluemix - BETA service)
2. Aggregate data (summaries, counts, etc) using Kafka Streams
3. A Web Dashboard app - frontend (Node.JS, D3.JS) consumes the streams and updates dashboard in real time.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean IBM MessageHub?

Comment: Hi Hans, yes. IBM Message Hub (in bluemix)

Answer (score 9):

You can definitely publish and subscribe  to Kafka (aka IBM MessageHub) using node.js and you can visualize Kafka data in all kinds of dashboards. Lately I have been using Node-Red and both the node-red-dashboard and node-red-contrib-web-worldmap with good results.

Pub/sub from nodejs apps can be done either via the Confluent REST Proxy (which IBM MessageHub uses) or via a native node.js client like the one Blizzard wrote on top of librdkafka (see https://github.com/blizzard/node-rdkafka). Confluent wrote some nodejs wrapper functions to make it easier to use the REST Proxy (see https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-node)

In terms of Kafka Streams, the main languages supported today are Java and Scala. You can mix node clients in Javascript with Streams apps in Java with no issue. Kafka Streams is implemented as just a Java library so your streams apps will definitely run in Bluemix in either a virtual machine or container and they will not require any additional cluster manager or third party  infrastructure.

UPDATE: IBM announces MessageHub now supports Kafka Streams

https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2017/06/28/messagehub-now-runs-kafka-0-10-2-1-supports-streams/

Comment: thank you Hans. I checked the version and looks like Bluemix is supporting Kafka v0,10 which has the streams app functionality. Are there any good examples written in Java which I can use and try. The Kafka connector beta service which connects to Cloudant looks like buggy

Comment: Some Kafka Streams examples in Java are here https://github.com/confluentinc/examples

Comment: The examples on the page asks to install confluent and zookeeper. Wonder how can this run in bluemix. bluemix already provides a kafka cluster, confluent and zookeeper services are not available.

Comment: IBM Message Hub already includes zookeeper and kafka so you can skip those steps because IBM has already installed this in Bluemix as part of MessageHub. It may even be the Confluent distribution since I notice the  use the Confluent REST Proxy too.

Comment: Bluemix doesn't support Kafka streams at this timeline , thank you

Comment: Also Ibm replaced zookeeper with its own jar, at this time. This has brought in limitations. So dropped idea of using Kafka streams for analytics in bluemix

Comment: That to bad if it's true. I suppose you could always chose to run the standard Apache Kafka components (including Streams) in Bluemix virtual machines or Bluemix containers, just as you can on Amazon AWS or Google Cloud. Then you would have the latest open source that is known to work without any IBM specific changes that break compatibility.

Comment: Soon Kafka Streams will not need to talk to zookeeper so it shouldn't matter. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4060

Comment: Thanks Hans. Wish it is supported in Bluemix. Limitations exist and clients using PaaS always want the infrastructure automation to save time and efforts. And it is a big deal since they already pay for PaaS and matters when functionality is removed.

Comment: The current version of Kafka Streams (0.10.2.1 as of 5/27/2017) has no zookeeper dependency so it might be time to revisit it for use on Bluemix